# Xen HVM: Can I make virtualisations if I'm a guest (domU)?

Tags: xen, domu

Maybe strange question. But as far as I understand HVM is full emulation of hardware. 
I have a VDS with 16gb ram and 8xeon, it's domU of XEN HVM. I don't want to run tons of daemons in one plate..

So my question is can I install any virtualisation host inside? KVM, XEN, OPENVIZ? If no maybe any other solutions exists?

my domU is freebsd (KVM port exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my question is can I install any virtualisation host inside?

Xen(only Linux), VirtualBox(any supported OS) and OpenVZ.

Xen/OpenVZ performance overhead typically 0.1%-4%.

Comment: kmv is impossible? is ther's any other virtualizations in BSD systems?

Comment: To run KVM, you need a processor that supports hardware virtualization. domU it has't. Try VirtualBox.

Comment: Not true, I/O performance is horrible in this setup

Comment: it's raid10 in there, dd shows 700MB/s =)